# Registering Google Glass as a device on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-glass

I'm programming with Glass for the first time, and I'm pretty new to Android Studio as well. I can't figure out how to make Glass a device in Android Studio the way I could for my Android phone. There is precious little advice on the web about it, and even less with people using Android Studio.

I have followed the GDK startup docs, like enabling usb debugging on the Glass, as well as installing the SDK and GDK.

Comment: which OS and version are you working with?

Comment: If you're on Windows, you'll need to install the USB driver. Open up "Device Manager" and see if Glass is listed. Also from command prompt type "adb devices" to see if ADB can find your Glass.

Answer (score 0):

If your Glass is already set up and you've enabled USB debugging, Android Studio *should* just recognize Glass.

Note that once plugged in the first time, you should see "Trust this computer?" on the Glass unit.  You have to accept in order for USB debugging to work.  If you don't accept, it won't allow the connection from your computer.

That said, things don't always work perfectly. If you don’t see “Trust this computer?” on your Glass unit after enabling debug mode:

- try turning debug mode off and on again.
- try unplugging/re-plugging the USB cord.
- try `adb kill-server`
- factory reset the Glass unit

You can type `adb devices` in a command prompt at any point to see which devices are connected.  If adb has permission to access Glass, then Android Studio does, too.